# How do I join multiple tables in SQL whose objects will be modeled using inheritance?

Tags: mysql, database, inheritance, modeling

For my university assignment I have to design some basic managment system for sicknesses and all for a school. I have decided to model some basic inheritance in the form of

- Person --> Student
- Person --> Staff
- Person --> Guardian

Person (PersonID, FirstName, LastName)

Student (StudentID (Which references the PersonID), ... )

The reason i decided to do this as I modeled this first in UML and had the inheritance in this.

I have another table which stored Incidents which have both StudentID, StaffID and GuardianID. However I was wondering how I would create a join in mysql which would display all three inherited people's names?

e.g.

Student.FirstName Student.LastName, Staff.FirstName, Staff.LastName etc...

How would I do this?

Or am i doing this completely wrong this way?

Thanks in advance.

http://pastebin.com/m263dd7 - Link to my DDL for the tables.

Comment: Wait, so a Staff Person inherits from a Student Person?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Ahh - new lines didn't show up -they are meant to all inherit from Person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no problem with the database design you've described.  It's always a bit awkward to model inheritance in SQL, but you've used the least problematic solution.

Here's a query to answer your question about retrieving the names of a student and staff member for a given incident:

```
SELECT ps.FirstName, ps.LastName, pf.FirstName, pf.LastName
FROM Incidents i
 JOIN Students s USING (student_id)
 JOIN Persons ps ON (s.student_id = ps.person_id)
 JOIN Staff f USING (staff_id)
 JOIN Persons pf ON (f.staff_id = pf.person_id)
WHERE i.incident_id = ?;
```

I'm assuming the `Incidents` table looks includes columns such as:

```
CREATE TABLE Incidents (
  incident_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  student_id  INT NOT NULL,
  staff_id    INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES Students(student_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (staff_id) REFERENCES Staff(staff_id)
);
```

Realistically, I'd expect some kind of many-to-many relationship between incidents and each of staff and students.  Otherwise, an incident can involve only one student and one staff member?

Comment: Thank you - your feedback fixed my problem - I've never used USING in regards to creating a JOIN.

Comment: Yep, USING is just a shortcut, to do an equality comparison against columns that have the same name in both tables.  If the columns are named differently, you need to write an explicit expression in an ON clause.

Answer (score 1):

This is not right. You should have a Person class, and other classes would determine that a certain Person is a Student, Staff, etc. What happens if you have a staff person that is also a student? What happens if the Student graduates?

It is a classic example of impedance mismatch between the relational model and the OO model.

You could have for example three tables:

PERSON
PersonId
LastName
FirstName

STUDENT 
StudentId
PersonId

STAFF
StaffId
PersonId

Comment: Sorry - I formatted it wrong and didn't noticed when i submitted.

Comment: What do you suggest I do when i model this sort of data?

Comment: So would modeling without a PersonID inside the Inherited class be a bad idea?

Comment: Not that it wouldn't be a good idea - it wouldn't work. At least in my experience when the relational model is involved it is better to accept it in your object model.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what the real usage, but it is not a good idea to use inheritence just for reusability.

At first sight, having a `Person` class in a university management system (something similar) does not seem right.

It would be better you mention the objective/purpose of the assignment - what is is supposed to do.